# AttributeError: 'ImageCard' object has no attribute 'source'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Good afternoon people.

I'm building an app that takes information from Firebase, all working beautifully!
The application grew and became too complex to be in a single file, so I'm separating it to make it more readable.
In my code below I take data from Firebase and show it in a list.
I happen to have two pieces of information, a FitImage with source and an MDLabel with text.

After I separated the code I'm getting the return below:

AttributeError: 'ImageCard' object has no attribute 'source'

1 - If I manually inform the image path, it works.
2 - Interestingly the text coming from Firebase works.

I'd appreciate your help trying to figure out why the text works and the image doesn't!

```
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

# Imports para trabalhar com Firebase
from config import config
import pyrebase


Builder.load_string("""
<ImageCard@MDCard>
    id: ec

    size_hint: ('180dp', None)
    ripple_behavior: True
    image:''
    text:''

    orientation:'vertical'

    FitImage:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25} 
        source: './images/user.png' # root.source
        size_hint: None, None
        width: dp(150) 
        height: dp(150) 
        #radius: [99, 99, 99, 99]

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        MDLabel:
            text:root.text
            halign:"center"
            #bold: True

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "New Screen Here"
        increment_width: "164dp"

        on_release: root.show_confirmation_dialog()

<ScreenRecycleView>:
    name: 'recycle_view' 

    FloatLayout:

        MDTextField:
            id: pesquisa

            helper_text: "Escreva um trecho da pesquisa e clique em pesquisar."
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            size_hint: .99, None
            halign: 'center' 
            multiline: False 


            hint_text: 'Digite o que procura'
            text_validate_unfocus: False
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.42, 'center_y': 0.84}
            padding: dp(15)        
            #size_hint_x: .75
            #on_text: root.on_kv_post(self, self.text)

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "magnify"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .95, "center_y": 0.84}
            on_release: root.on_kv_post(self, pesquisa.text)            
        

        #:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex        
        MDBoxLayout:
            
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
            RecycleView:
                data: root.image_data
                viewclass: "ImageCard"
                RecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    default_size: dp(155), dp(200)
     
                    padding: dp(5) # Determina o espaçamento entre um widget e outro pelos lados               
                    spacing: dp(5) # Determina o espaçamento entre um widget e outro de cima para baixo
                    default_size_hint: 1, None ##### Define a largura do widget sempre próximo as bordas
                    size_hint_y: None ##### Associado a default_size_hint
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    #ripple_behavior: True""")    

class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ImageCard(MDCard):
    dialog = None
    text = StringProperty()
    source = StringProperty()

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                #title="Address:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="OK",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()

class ScreenRecycleView(Screen):   
    image_data = ListProperty()

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget, text="", search=False):
        
        # Inicializando o banco de dados.
        self.firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        self.db = self.firebase.database()

        self.produtos = self.db.child("Produtos").get(token='**************************************')
        
        #self.ids.rv3.data = []
        self.image_data = []
        
        for produto in self.produtos.each():
            if text.upper() in produto.val()['nmproduto']:
                if produto.val()['url'] != 'SemUrl':
                    self.image_data.append(
                        {"source": produto.val()['url'],
                        "text": produto.val()['nmproduto']
                        }
                    )
                else:
                    self.image_data.append(
                        {"source": './images/sem_imagem.png',
                        "text": produto.val()['nmproduto']
                        }
                    ) 

        #print(json.dumps(self.ids.rv3.data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Try changing `<ImageCard@MDCard>` with `<ImageCard>`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought!

On ImageCard@MDCard it was like this:

```
 image:'' <<<======
 text:''
```

I modified it to:

```
 source:''
 text:''
```

and solved. Interestingly it worked when the code was mixed up.